# BC42322 VB.NET Runtime errors might occur when converting 'String' to 'IFormatProvider'

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I'm trying to migrate old VB6(Visual Basic 6.0) Project to VB.net framework 4.6x.
But I had to migrate it to .net framework 2.0 first.

I used to convert numbers in TextBox to formatted numbers using ToString as below.
In Visual Studio 2017 .net framework 2.0, I have BC42322 warning.
Is there a way to solve this?

```
txtDividend.Text = txtDividend.Text.ToString("###,###,##0")
```

I also have

```
On Error GoTo Error_Handle
```

at the start of the function to handle characters in that textbox

Comment: `On Error GoTo Error_Handle` has been replaced by `Try...Catch...Finally...End Try` Look that up and use it instread.

Comment: Thank you [Mary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8367626/mary). I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` property is already a string, and the `ToString()` method for string doesn't have the overload you want.

Since it seems this same text field can hold both the formatted and unformatted version of a value, what you may want to do is first strip off any formatting, convert to a numeric type like `Integer` or `Decimal`, and then use the `ToString()` method from there:

```
Public Function FormatDividend(dividend As String) As String
    Dim extraCharacters As New Regex("[^\d,.-]")
    dividend = extraCharacters.Replace(dividend, "")
    Return FormatDividend(CDec(dividend))
End Function
Public Function FormatDividend(dividend As Decimal) As String
    Return Dividend.ToString("###,###,##0")
End Function
```

You can call those functions like this:

```
txtDividend.Text = FormatDividend(txtDividend.Text)
```

And of course you can tweak that expression however you want, or change the overload and cast to use Integer instead of Decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to migrate from an environment where "1000".ToString("###,##0") produced 1,000, you will want that to work in your new (.net).  That solution is to create an extension method that essentially provides the overload.

```
<Extension>
Function ToString(input as String, format as String) as String
    Static numericOnly As Regex = New Regex("[^\d.-]")
    Dim asDec as Decimal
    Decimal.TryParse(numericOnly.Replace(input, ""), asDec)
    Return asDec.ToString(format)
End Function
```

Comment: @Oblivionaccess: fixed a couple of errors (typing from ipad).  Should compile now.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have more than one TextBox to use format, I upgraded [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn)'s answer to use format TextBox in my project.

First, I created CommonFunction.vb module file

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module CommonFunction
    Public Function FormatNumberInText(text As String, format As String) As String
        Dim extraCharacters As New Regex("[^\d,.-]")
        text = extraCharacters.Replace(text, "")
        Return FormatNumberInText(CDec(text), format)
    End Function
    Public Function FormatNumberInText(text As Decimal, format As String) As String
        Return text.ToString(format)
    End Function
End Module
```

and in my TextBox vb file, I used it as below.

```
txtDividend.Text = FormatNumberInText(txtDividend.Text, "###,###,##0")
txtDividendRatio.Text = FormatNumberInText(txtDividendRatio.Text, "###,###,##0.0#")
```

Thank you [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the ToString() Method is designed to convert other types to a string and format them as desired. It was not designed to format an existing string. The simplest way I have found around this problem is to convert your string into another data type and then apply the ToString() Method.

So in your case I would convert to a double using the CDbl() Method:

txtDividend.Text = CDbl(txtDividend.Text).ToString("###,###,##0")